# My app start automatically after I cancel it

Tags: java, android, service, alarm

I design alarm manager with repeated in specific time. But when I cancel it on on click method after seconds(time Interval) service start  automatically itself.

I want activate service on button click and repeat in interval. and after restaring phone wants to start service too.

any Idea?

here its my manifest code :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alarm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"

    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"  android:enabled="true"/>

   <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".AlarmService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My AlarmReceiver :

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "BANANEALARM";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
Intent intent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
NotificationManager notificationManager;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "starttt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//  if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Log.d(TAG, "in onreceive");
     Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
      context.startService(service1);
//  }
}

}
```

My BootCompleteReceiver

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

      if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {

          Toast.makeText(context, "Boot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    this.scheduleAlarms(context, calendar);
}  
}
private void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt, Calendar c) {
    AlarmManager alarManager = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AlarmService.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     alarManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,c.getTimeInMillis(),getInterval(), pi);
        }
private int getInterval(){
    int days = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 1;
    int seconds = 60;
    int milliseconds = 1000;
    int repeatMS = minutes*  seconds * milliseconds;
    return repeatMS;
}
}
```

And my MainActivity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "BANANEALARM";
public AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent alarmIntent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Button btn,btn2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            setAlarm();
            }
     });

    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_s);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopservice();
            }
     });

}

public void stopservice()
 {
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                // Tell the user about what we did.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

```
public void triggerAlarm(View v){
    setAlarm();
}

public void setAlarm(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("com.example.alarm.ACTION");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            getInterval(), pendingIntent);


    Log.d(TAG,"alarmStartTime: " );
}

private int getInterval(){
    int days = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 1;
    int seconds = 60;
    int milliseconds = 1000;
    int repeatMS = minutes*  seconds * milliseconds;
    return repeatMS;
}

@Override 
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    cancelNotifications();
    setAlarm();
}

public void cancelNotifications(){
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

}

Comment: I think becz of your PendingIntent code in setAlarm().

Comment: Thanks.solved. problem was on next answer as u said,

Comment: okay i'll put as ans so you can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `stopservice`method, code`alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)`, the `pendingIntent` is always null.

Try replace

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent`

to

`pendingIntent = PendingIntent`

in your `setAlarm` method.

Hope it helps.